# Master page titles

Tags: asp.net, title, master-pages

Iv been trying to do this for 2 hours, and google didnt help either. What im trying to do is, set the master page title to "My web page", and then from the child pages i want to append to this title.

I tried in the child page:

```
this.Title = this.Title + "- About Us";
```

But all this did was set the title to "- About us" and "My web page" was lost. Anyone please know how i can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Where's the `+` between `this.Title` and the `string`?

Comment: Which event are you running this code in? `Page_Load`, `Page_Init` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like `Master.Page.Title` instead of `this.Title`